# Python gzip gives null bytes

Tags: python, gzip

I'm trying to parse some log files in Python, but my responses always return only null bytes.

I've confirmed that the file in question does contain data:

```
$ zcat Events.log.gz | wc -c
188371128
$ zcat Events.log.gz | head
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,863: {"deviceType":"A16ZV8BU3SN1N3",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,878: {"deviceType":"A1CTGXB4BA274T",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,886: {"deviceType":"A1DL2DVDQVK3Q",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,911: {"deviceType":"A2CZFJ2RKY7SE2",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,937: {"deviceType":"A2JTEGS8GUPDOF",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,963: {"appOtaState":"ota",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,971: {"deviceType":"A1DL2DVDQVK3Q",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:36,006: {"deviceType":"A2JTEGS8GUPDOF",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:36,013: {"deviceType":"A1CTGXB4BA274T",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:36,041: {"deviceType":"A1DL2DVDQVK3Q",[REDACTED]}
```

But attempting to read it in Python gives only null bytes:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.9 (unknown, Sep 14 2016, 17:46:59)
[GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> filename = 'Events.log.gz'
>>> import gzip
>>> content = gzip.open(filename).read()
>>> len(content)
188371128
>>> for i in range(10):
...   content[i*10000:(i*10000)+10]
...
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I've tried explicitly setting `'mode`' to either `'r'` or `'rb'`, with no difference in result.

I've also tried `subprocess.Popen(['zcat', filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()`, with the same response.

Perhaps relevantly, when I tried to `zcat` the file to another file, the output was a binary file:

```
$ zcat Events.log.gz > /tmp/logoutput
$ less /tmp/logoutput
"/tmp/logoutput" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
[y]
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@...
$ head /tmp/logoutput
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,863: {"deviceType":"A16ZV8BU3SN1N3",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,878: {"deviceType":"A1CTGXB4BA274T",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,886: {"deviceType":"A1DL2DVDQVK3Q",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,911: {"deviceType":"A2CZFJ2RKY7SE2",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,937: {"deviceType":"A2JTEGS8GUPDOF",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,963: {"appOtaState":"ota",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:35,971: {"deviceType":"A1DL2DVDQVK3Q",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:36,006: {"deviceType":"A2JTEGS8GUPDOF",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:36,013: {"deviceType":"A1CTGXB4BA274T",[REDACTED]}
17 Jan 2018 08:10:36,041: {"deviceType":"A1DL2DVDQVK3Q",[REDACTED]}
```

Comment: content[i*10000:(i*10000)+10],  can you expalin for us what does this statement do?

Comment: Try `zcat Events.log.gz | hexdump -C | head` and you might find the first 100k bytes (which you checked) are `\x00`.

Comment: NUL bytes are ignored by terminals -- unless you send them to a program like `less`, they're just silently not printed. So it's completely reasonable behavior for you to be getting the output that you have if your input file has a whole bunch of NUL bytes there in the compressed data; `zcat` to the terminal won't show 'em, but inspection from Python or viewing with `less` will.

Comment: @haifzhan, it's slicing out 10 bytes from a point (10,000*i) bytes in.

Comment: @scubbo, instead of spot-checking individual slices, try removing all the NULs from your Python string and seeing what's left.

Comment: D'oh! Yep, you're absolutely right @metatoaster and @Charles Duffy - I don't know exactly how to interpret `hexdump` responses, but it seems pretty clear that this file is just start-padded with a *lot* of null: https://pastebin.com/aLUq9kUZ. Knowing that, I should be able to press on from here. Thanks!

Comment: Basically the leftmost columns will show `00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  `, the first column is the starting byte position (in hex) of the input, subsequent is the raw hex value of the bytes.  An asterisk might be in place of a gap for a bunch of null bytes skipping ahead to the next position where there are non-null bytes.  The third line, first column should show a hex number > 0x186a0.